# Server freeze after IdTCPClient connect

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have two applications that communicate with each other using TCPServer and a TCPClient components.
The server starts in hidden mode:`Application.ShowMainForm: = false;`

Just an icon on systemtray interacts with the user.After run the server, if I run the client and and connect to the server this freeze, but if I change the server property `Application.ShowMainForm` to **true**  everything works perfectly. This is the code I'm using:

**Client app:**

```
procedure TFormCliente.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    cliente.Connect;
  except
    hint1.ActivateHint(FormCliente,'Error.' + #13 +
     'Verify if server is running','VCall',5000); //hint1 is a Jed component
  end;
end;
```

**Server app:**

```
[...]
private
  FConexoes: TList;
[...]


type
  PClient   = ^TClient;
  TClient   = record
    PeerIP      : string[15];            { Client IP address }
    HostName    : String[40];            { Hostname }
    Connected,                           { Time of connect }
    LastAction  : TDateTime;             { Time of last transaction }
    AContext      : Pointer;             { Pointer to thread }
  end;
[...]

procedure TfrmServer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FConexoes := TList.Create;
end;

procedure TFrmServer.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FConexoes.Free;
end;

procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  NewClient: PClient; 
begin
  GetMem(NewClient, SizeOf(TClient));
  NewClient.PeerIP      := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  NewClient.HostName    := GStack.HostByAddress(NewClient.PeerIP);
  NewClient.Connected   := Now;
  NewClient.LastAction  := NewClient.Connected;
  NewClient.AContext    := AContext;
  AContext.Data         := TObject(NewClient);
  ListView1.Items.Add.Caption:=NewClient.HostName;
end;
```

If the server form is visible, the client hostname is added to the listview, but if the server form is not visible, and run cliente and connect, the server freezes until I kill the client process. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This worked ok for me.  I received an exception when I closed my client (ie disconnected) but Disposing of AContext.Data and setting it to nil resolved that issue.  Maybe it's related to that.

Comment: Indy events are multithreaded, never update the GUI from a thread other than the main thread, you must use calls to Synchronize() to update the GUI.

Comment: Whosrdaddy So how can I do this?  Putting a ButtonX.click from a thread is an alternative to update GUI?

Comment: The line that accesses the `TListView` is not thread-safe. Use the  `TThread.Synchronize()` method or the `TIdSync` class to invoke that line safely.

Comment: @RemyLebeau please write a example...

Comment: @V.Salles: Examples of `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TIdSync` are all over the place. Did you try doing a search yet?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, actually found several, but using these solutions could not get the hostname using the variable AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;

How can I use the variable up through an outside event `IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);`?

Comment: I have posted many examples of `OnConnect` and `OnDisconnect` events posting data to the UI thread, including information obtained from the `TIdContext`. I will provide another example for you since you can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

Your direct access of the `TListView` in the `OnConnect` event is not thread-safe.  That in of itself can cause deadlocks and crashes.  Try this instead:

```
type
  PClient   = ^TClient;
  TClient   = record
    PeerIP      : string;                { Client IP address }
    HostName    : String;                { Hostname }
    Connected,                           { Time of connect }
    LastAction  : TDateTime;             { Time of last transaction }
    AContext    : Pointer;               { Pointer to thread }
  end;

procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Client: PClient; 
begin
  New(Client);
  try
    Client.PeerIP      := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
    Client.HostName    := GStack.HostByAddress(Client.PeerIP);
    Client.Connected   := Now;
    Client.LastAction  := Client.Connected;
    Client.AContext    := AContext;

    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      var
        Item: TListItem;
      begin
        Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
        Item.Data := Client;
        Item.Caption := Client.HostName;
      end
    );
  except
    Dispose(Client);
    raise;
  end;

  AContext.Data := TObject(Client);
end;

procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Client: PClient; 
begin
  Client := PClient(AContext.Data); 
  AContext.Data := nil;

  if Client = nil then Exit;

  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    var
      Item: TListItem;
    begin
      Item := ListView1.FindData(0, Client, True, False);
      if Item <> nil then
        Item.Delete;
    end
  );

  Dispose(NewClient);
end;
```